# Does getting random SIGTRAP signals (in MinGW-gdb) is a sign of memory corruption?

Tags: c++, windows, memory-management, gdb, mingw

I wrote my own reference counted memory manager c++ (for fun) and I'm sure it isn't perfect ;) . And now when I'm trying to use it I got random SIGTRAP signals. If I comment out every line which are in connection with that memory manager everything runs fine. Getting SIGTRAP-s instead of SIGSEGV is quite strange.
I know that SIGTRAP-s are thrown when the program hits a breakpoint, but no breakpoint is set. I read in an other thread that debug builds of the exe's and dll's must be up to date. They are up to date and so it is not the reason.

Does anyone know why is this happening?

Comment: Since you are on Windows, you almost certainly are *not* getting any SIGTRAPs (which are a UNIX concept and don't apply on Windows at all).

Why don't you edit your question to describe what you actually observe?

Comment: Well MinGW says SIGTRAP under windows too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After searching on Google I realized that those sigtraps are same as those warnings you get in MSVC++ saying "Windows has triggered a breakpoint in xxxx.exe. This may be due to a corruption of the heap, and indicates a bug blahblahblah"...

So it seems yes, unexpected sigtraps can indicate memory corrupction (quite strange...)

And I found my bug too. The MM is in a static library which is linked to a dll. And that static lib and the dll is linked to my exe. So there were two memory managers, one in my exe and one in my dll. If call the initialization method of the MM. It initialized the MM in my exe but not in the dll so the dll went without init. I solved this by not linking my exe against that static library.

Answer (score 2):

I'd throw in a guess that you might be calling mismatched new/delete or malloc/free implementations - So something was allocated by your memory manager but when the memory is released you end up with the default delete/free implementation.

Set a breakpoint on the signal and see whether there is free() or operator delete on the stack and whether that is the implementation of said function which you would expect.