# malloc producing SIGTRAP error

Tags: c

```
char *word = malloc(sizeof(char) * (pos + 1));
```

is producing an SIGTRAP error. `pos` is an `int`.

How do I know this is the line? Process of elimination with break points.

I searched and did not find any information on this function producing this error. What should I do?

Comment: [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475262/what-causes-a-sigtrap-in-a-debug-session)

Comment: How do I find what might have corrupted the heap? I'm using windows and codelite IDE.

Comment: "*How do I find what might have corrupted the heap?*" Run your program using a memory checker. I'd recommend Valgrind (http://valgrind.org), but am not sure whether it's available on you platfrom.

Comment: Also `sizeof (char)` is `1` by definition.

Comment: Also^2 `malloc()` takes a `size_t` (which is unsigned) as argument, not an `int`. Saying this, could by any chance the `pos - 1` in your source had evaluated to a negative value, that is `pos` had been `<=0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many memory debuggers available on Windows (though I haven't tried them by myself):

- [Is there a good Valgrind substitute for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows)

I'd recommend you to try Application Verifier from MS:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371695(v=vs.85).aspx

It should be able to catch heap corruption.

But before you start relying on such a large and complicated software, you can simply `printf` the value of arguments to `malloc()` and `free()` at all places.  You will find something odd in the output.