# What does this SIGTRAP mean?

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception

I was wondering if someone could provide some insight as to what is causing this SIGTRAP to occur. If someone could also provide suggestions as to what I could do from here to debug this better, that would be greatly appreciated as I am unable to replicate it reliably.

```
Hardware Model:      iPad mini 3 (iPad4,8)
Process:         SceneDoc [330]
Path:            /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/1CB3551A-24A3-4FA8-B2ED-8AF993F7DA43/SceneDoc.app/SceneDoc
Identifier:      com.scenedoc.SceneDocAppAppStore
Code Type:       arm64
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2015-03-23 15:42:57 +0000
Launch Time:     2015-03-23 15:42:57 +0000
OS Version:      iOS 8.2 (12D508)

Exception Type:  SIGTRAP
Crashed Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'SIGTRAP', reason: ''

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                0x185629750 _CFHash + 22352
1   CoreFoundation                0x185625d44 _CFBasicHashFindBucket + 7492
2   CoreFoundation                0x185625900 _CFDictionaryGetValue + 6400
3   CoreFoundation                0x1856d6658 [CFPrefsPlistSource alreadylocked_setValue:forKey:] + 730712
4   CoreFoundation                0x185784830 [CFPrefsSource setValue:forKey:] + 1443888
5   CoreFoundation                0x185783dc8 [CFPrefsSource withSourceForIdentifier:user:byHost:container:perform:] + 1441224
6   CoreFoundation                0x185787658 __CFPreferencesSetValueWithContainer + 1455704
7   Foundation                    0x18656b600 [NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults) setObject:forKey:] + 128512
8   SceneDoc                      0x10025673c [Prefs savePrefs] (Prefs.m:503)
9   SceneDoc                      0x100259e0c [Prefs setLogoutDuration] (Prefs.m:2067)
10  SceneDoc                      0x10014a518 [SDCThriftGCDManager refreshToken:] (SDCThriftGCDManager.m:484)
11  UIKit                         0x18a1e2444 [UIApplication workspaceNoteAssertionExpirationImminent:] + 2729028
12  FrontBoardServices            0x18db31604 ___31-[FBSSerialQueue (performAsync:0)
13  CoreFoundation                0x185702d70 ___CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 912752
14  CoreFoundation                0x185701e78 ___CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 908920
15  CoreFoundation                0x18570049c ___CFRunLoopRun + 902300
16  CoreFoundation                0x18562d1f4 _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 37364
17  GraphicsServices              0x18e9776fc _GSEventRunModal + 46844
18  UIKit                         0x189fbe10c _UIApplicationMain + 483596
19  SceneDoc                      0x1000ceae4 main (main.m:12)
20  libdyld.dylib                 0x196faaa08 _start + 10760

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x1970a8c24 _kevent64 + 3108
1   libdispatch.dylib             0x196f7f99c __dispatch_source_invoke + 14748

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x1970a8e0c _mach_msg_trap + 3596
1   CoreFoundation                0x185702218 ___CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 909848
2   CoreFoundation                0x18570016c ___CFRunLoopRun + 901484
3   CoreFoundation                0x18562d1f4 _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 37364
4   CoreFoundation                0x18567f370 _CFRunLoopRun + 373616
5   CoreMotion                    0x18602fe14 0x185fe8000 + 294420
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x19715fdc8 __pthread_body + 15816
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x19715fd24 __pthread_body + 15652
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x19715cef8 _thread_start + 3832

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x1970a8e0c _mach_msg_trap + 3596
1   CoreFoundation                0x185702218 ___CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 909848
2   CoreFoundation                0x18570016c ___CFRunLoopRun + 901484
3   CoreFoundation                0x18562d1f4 _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 37364
4   CFNetwork                     0x18512e2a4 [NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 647844
5   Foundation                    0x186642308 ___NSThread__main__ + 1008392
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x19715fdc8 __pthread_body + 15816
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x19715fd24 __pthread_body + 15652
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x19715cef8 _thread_start + 3832

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x1970c3498 _select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 111768
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x19715fdc8 __pthread_body + 15816
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x19715fd24 __pthread_body + 15652
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x19715cef8 _thread_start + 3832

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x1970c3c78 ___workq_kernreturn + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x19715cef0 _start_wqthread + 3824

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x1970c3c78 ___workq_kernreturn + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x19715cef0 _start_wqthread + 3824

Thread 0 crashed with arm64 Thread state:
    cpsr: 0x60000000    fp: 0x16fd7a0a0     lr: 0x185625d44     pc: 0x185629750 
    sp: 0x16fd7a090     x0: 0               x1: 0               x10: 0x1        
    x11: 0              x12: 0x13e00ceb0    x13: 0x61a5975c10e9    x14: 0x5cd61a0d8643
    x15: 0x8c           x16: 0x19692a4d8    x17: 0x1856d65bc    x18: 0          
    x19: 0              x2: 0x17425fce0     x20: 0x174266f00    x21: 0          
    x22: 0x16fd7a1f0    x23: 0x17007ffc0    x24: 0x1975c8750    x25: 0x1975cb9c0
    x26: 0x19b0d80a8    x27: 0x19b0d4088    x28: 0              x3: 0           
    x4: 0x16fd7a2c8     x5: 0x2a            x6: 0x2a            x7: 0           
    x8: 0x5             x9: 0x185629650
```

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475262/what-causes-a-sigtrap-in-a-debug-session) this answer may be helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much for your link meth, but I am unsure how to apply that information to my situation. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have originated from my key somehow being nil when it tried to set the object in the NSUserDefaults. Interestingly enough, it doesn't crash in the simulator.