# When can a running process in Unix receive a SIGTRAP (value 5) signal?

Tags: unix, process, signals

There is a one process called NSM in my code. Which abruptly got a SIGTRAP signal and it got killed. So just wanted to know that when can a process get a SIGTRAP signal?

Comment: Any time, that's how signals work. Normally SIGTRAP is a debugging signal - trace/breakpoint. So likely someone tried to attach a process debugger to it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3475444/2793118

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a Sigtrap in a Debug Session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475262/what-causes-a-sigtrap-in-a-debug-session)

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments, it is a signal so can be triggered at any time. SIGTRAP signal is handled by the debugger; in the absence of a debugger it is quite natural for the process to be terminated. If you are using static libraries in your project then you are not linking them appropriately. Without further information in your question, I suggest you to check your linking with libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Some libraries raise a SIGTRAP upon some critical errors.

For example, in the GLIB, `g_thread_join()` service which joins a thread, relies on `pthread_join()` from the underlying PTHREAD library. In order to prevent deadlocks, the latter checks if two threads try to join with each other or the current thread tries to join itself. If either case occurs, the **EDEADLK** errno is returned to the caller. On such error, the calling GLIB raises a **SIGTRAP** signal. Hence, if a debugger is attached to the running process, this permits to debug the issue.