# Crash log from a published app

Tags: ios, swift, crash

This is a log from a crash report of a published app. I don't have any more details about the crash except that it happened on an iPhone 5.

I don't see Last Exception Backtrace block here so I don't know how to pinpoint the error and fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.2 (14C92)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000000e7ffdefe
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   SpeakProject                  0x001093b8 0xf4000 + 86968
1   SpeakProject                  0x00110710 0xf4000 + 116496
2   SpeakProject                  0x001108b8 0xf4000 + 116920
3   SpeakProject                  0x00110808 0xf4000 + 116744
4   RxSwift                       0x0061a254 0x5c0000 + 369236
5   RxSwift                       0x0061a42c 0x5c0000 + 369708
6   RxSwift                       0x00621cd8 0x5c0000 + 400600
7   RxSwift                       0x00621d80 0x5c0000 + 400768
8   RxSwift                       0x00649ec4 0x5c0000 + 564932
9   RxSwift                       0x0064a470 0x5c0000 + 566384
10  RxSwift                       0x005c72a0 0x5c0000 + 29344
11  RxSwift                       0x005c7400 0x5c0000 + 29696
12  RxSwift                       0x005c7ff8 0x5c0000 + 32760
13  SpeakProject                  0x001270dc 0xf4000 + 209116
14  SpeakProject                  0x00127674 0xf4000 + 210548
15  SpeakProject                  0x00127740 0xf4000 + 210752
16  Alamofire                     0x001d69fc 0x190000 + 289276
17  Alamofire                     0x001d94ec 0x190000 + 300268
18  libdispatch.dylib             0x1d396096 0x1d395000 + 4246
19  libdispatch.dylib             0x1d396082 0x1d395000 + 4226
20  libdispatch.dylib             0x1d39a5fc 0x1d395000 + 22012
21  CoreFoundation                0x1dcac4a6 0x1dbef000 + 775334
22  CoreFoundation                0x1dcaa78e 0x1dbef000 + 767886
23  CoreFoundation                0x1dbf9532 0x1dbef000 + 42290
24  CoreFoundation                0x1dbf9340 0x1dbef000 + 41792
25  GraphicsServices              0x1f3d0bfc 0x1f3c7000 + 39932
26  UIKit                         0x22e07e26 0x22d8e000 + 499238
27  UIKit                         0x22e02550 0x22d8e000 + 476496
28  SpeakProject                  0x00125784 0xf4000 + 202628
29  libdyld.dylib                 0x1d3c350a 0x1d3c0000 + 13578

Thread 1 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x1d48384c 0x1d482000 + 6220
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x1d48363e 0x1d482000 + 5694
2   CoreFoundation                0x1dcac2f8 0x1dbef000 + 774904
3   CoreFoundation                0x1dcaa5f6 0x1dbef000 + 767478
4   CoreFoundation                0x1dbf9532 0x1dbef000 + 42290
5   CoreFoundation                0x1dbf9340 0x1dbef000 + 41792
6   Foundation                    0x1e55388a 0x1e548000 + 47242
7   Foundation                    0x1e572630 0x1e548000 + 173616
8   UIKit                         0x2370e2b2 0x22d8e000 + 9962162
9   Foundation                    0x1e63cb10 0x1e548000 + 1002256
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x1d54da26 0x1d54a000 + 14886
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x1d54d94c 0x1d54a000 + 14668
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x1d54b49c 0x1d54a000 + 5276

Thread 2 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x1d48384c 0x1d482000 + 6220
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x1d48363e 0x1d482000 + 5694
2   CoreFoundation                0x1dcac2f8 0x1dbef000 + 774904
3   CoreFoundation                0x1dcaa5f6 0x1dbef000 + 767478
4   CoreFoundation                0x1dbf9532 0x1dbef000 + 42290
5   CoreFoundation                0x1dbf9340 0x1dbef000 + 41792
6   CFNetwork                     0x1e2d4488 0x1e219000 + 767112
7   Foundation                    0x1e63cb10 0x1e548000 + 1002256
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x1d54da26 0x1d54a000 + 14886
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x1d54d94c 0x1d54a000 + 14668
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x1d54b49c 0x1d54a000 + 5276

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x1d499744 0x1d482000 + 96068
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x1d54b9a0 0x1d54a000 + 6560
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x1d54b490 0x1d54a000 + 5264

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x1d499744 0x1d482000 + 96068
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x1d54b9a0 0x1d54a000 + 6560
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x1d54b490 0x1d54a000 + 5264

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x1d54b488 0x1d54a000 + 5256

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x1d54b488 0x1d54a000 + 5256

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x1d54b488 0x1d54a000 + 5256

Thread 8:

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x15f70420    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x0000000c      r3: 0x00000008
    r4: 0x15f61450    r5: 0x00000000      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x003b2a58
    r8: 0x00000001    r9: 0x15f70424     r10: 0x15f70420     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x0016c424    sp: 0x003b2a00      lr: 0x001090e8      pc: 0x001093b8
  cpsr: 0x20000010
```

Comment: A breakpoint doesn't strike me as a fatal exception.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475262/what-causes-a-sigtrap-in-a-debug-session

Comment: app is crashes on iphone and i cant launch it again.

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash report

Comment: I've simplified the question and its description